# Large Cardinal Principles that Imply $\Sigma_3^1$-Generic Absoluteness

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

It is known that (light-face) $\Sigma_3^1$ generic absoluteness is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$: Friedman and Bagaria showed that it holds in the $\text{Coll}(\omega, < \kappa)$ extension of $V$ where $\kappa$ is a $\Sigma_2$-correct cardinal.

My questions are about what large cardinal principles can prove $\Sigma_3^1$-generic absoluteness. In particular:

1) If $0^\sharp$ exists (or even $x^\sharp$ exists for all reals $x$), does (light-face) $\Sigma_3^1$-generic absoluteness holds.

2) What if there is a measurable cardinal, then does $\Sigma_3^1$-generic absoluteness hold?

Is there any large cardinal whose existence implies $\Sigma_3^1$ generic-absoluteness?

Comment: If my memory serves me right, a measurable implies $\Sigma^1_3$-absoluteness for forcing smaller than the measurable. So the existence of a proper class of measurable cardinals implies $\Sigma^1_3$-absoluteness.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you know where I can find a proof of the result you mentioned?

Comment: It was mentioned in a course about generic absoluteness and stationary tower forcing, and was attributed to Martin-Solovay. No concrete reference was given, or else I would have probably post it as an answer.

Comment: There is a proof (or at least a sketch) in [these notes](http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/Appalachian/steel_cmu_2015_files/Iteration-Ultrapowers.pdf) by Steel (Theorem 2.13).

Answer (score 10):

A proper class of measurables more than suffices.

It suffices for the generic absoluteness to have X-sharp exists for every *set* of ordinals X.  Then the Martin-Solovay tree can be constructed throughout On.

One place to look is below.  The definition of the Martin-Solovay tree (I seem to recall) is given for an arbitrary cardinal $\kappa$, but even if it is only given for $\omega_1$ just replace $\omega_1$ by $\kappa$, and take the union of the trees on all regular cardinals $\kappa$ to get a tree on  $On$.

A. Kechris Homogeneous Trees and Projective Scales.
Cabal seminar 77-79: Proceedings of the Caltech-UCLA Logic Seminar 1977-1979
1981,Eds.A. Kechris, D.A. Martin, and Y. Moschovakis
839, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics Series, Pages 33-73

Comment: The existence of sharps (as in Philip's second paragraph) is also necessary, so this assumption is optimal.

Comment: @Andres: One might even say that the consistency bound is... sharp :-P

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Is sharps really necessary? Bagaria and Friedman showed that it consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that (lightface) $\Sigma_3^1$-generic absoluteness holds, for example in the $\text{Coll}(\omega, <\lambda)$ extension where $\lambda$ is a $\Sigma_2$-correct cardinal (which is not a large cardinal).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo In your paper "Projective Well-Ordering of the Reals" Theorem 3 seems to be what you are referring to. But the definition of generic absoluteness is stronger something like a two-step generic absoluteness. Also what is the sharp of an arbitary set. Should the existence of $A^\sharp$ be equivalent to there is an elementary embedding of $L[A]$ to $L[A]$? Can it be some kind of mouse?

Comment: @William Yes.${}$

Comment: Why is $\textbf{Ord}^\sharp$ required for $Σ^1_3$ generic absoluteness to hold, but not $\mathbb{R}^\sharp$? How should I understand the conclusion in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02897063  ?

Answer (score 7):

Re a proof of this result: I once wrote up an elementary proof of this which avoids the Martin-Solovay tree: See Theorem 1 of  https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/talks-barcelona.dvi

Comment: Quite nice, +1!